# what's the result of 1 + undefined

Tags: javascript

```
1 + undefined = ?
```

1. first, String(undefined) get string "undefined"
2. second, 1 + "undefined" = "1undefined"

what's wrong?

I run it in chrome console ,it return `NaN`.

can you pls explain the result?

I think it should be "1undefined".
tks

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. Can you show in code which result returns what?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: my answer is "1undefined",but the correct answer is "NAN"

Comment: I'm not sure but if you add integer to string in JS then you get another string as the operator is overloaded/

Comment: Here: http://es5.github.com/#x11.6.1.

Comment: To elaborate, neither `1` nor `undefined` are strings, so they're coerced to numbers. `Number(undefined)` is `NaN`, and `1 + NaN` is still `NaN`.

Comment: Why do you think `undefined` gets converted to a string? It doesn't.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`NaN` is the result of a failed `Number` operation.

```
1 + undefined           // NaN
"1" + undefined         // "1undefined"
1 + "" + undefined      // "1undefined"
1 + ("" + undefined)    // "1undefined"
typeof NaN              // "number"
typeof undefined        // "undefined"
NaN === NaN             // false (it's not reflexive!)
undefined === undefined // true (it's reflexive)
NaN.toString()          // "NaN"
```

`NaN` means **Not a Number** where a number was expected. Any Number operation with `NaN` will result in `NaN` as well.

Comment: 1 + undefined // NaN  why undefined is coverted to 'NAN'

Comment: It's not NAN, it's NaN (note the case on the _a_, JavaScript is case-sensitive). undefined is not being _converted_ to anything. You perform a `+` operation with operands `1` (Number) and `undefined`. The result of `Number + undefined` is **not a number** or `NaN`. `NaN` is a special kind of `Number`, like `Infinity` and it has some very peculiar properties.

Comment: @looping: You ask why? Because the specification says so: http://es5.github.com/#x9.3. You might or might not agree with this decision.

Answer (score 2):

You expect a string concatenation, but this will only happen if you have at least one string. And in your example nothing is a string. `1` is not a string and `undefined` is not a string.

Answer (score 1):

1 + undefined = NaN

When you do `1 + "undefined"` you concatinate the 1 to the String `"undefined"` resulting in the string `"1undefined"`

undefined is nothing or like Null in other languages (variable is not set)

In Javascript null is an expected absense (set to null somewhere) of a value and undefined is an unexpected absense of a value (never set)

What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: undefined an null both suggest absence of values. But null means an expected absence of value whereas undefined is an unexpected absence of value. So you cannot say that they are same. 1 + null = 1.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var charsLeft = 35 - (currentWord?.length ?? 0)
```

Thought that this code would come handy to someone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).