# Difference between var name; and var name = 0;

Tags: javascript, variables

I want to sum up `myArray` where i declared `var sumUpArray = 0`. It return the correct sum of `myArray` which is 6.

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 3];
var sumUpArray = 0;

for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  sumUpArray = sumUpArray + myArray[i];
}

console.log(sumUpArray);
```

But when I declared `var sumUpArray;` it return `NaN`.

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 3];
var sumUpArray;

for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  sumUpArray = sumUpArray + myArray[i];
}

console.log(sumUpArray);
```

What is the difference between the two declaration of variable?

Comment: Did you check what the value of `sumUpArray` is before the loop in the latter code?

Comment: `undefined` + any number returns `NaN`

Comment: When you use var sumUpArray, its value is undefined. So, if you add 0 to an undefined value, it will be NaN - Not a Number

Comment: By default the value of sumUpArray is undefined. When you sum undefined with a number, you are getting NaN.

Comment: Some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14977803/1823841

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example you declared the variable but didn't assign any value, so it starts out as `undefined`. I think you maybe expected it to be auto-assigned to 0, which it does not.

Then you tried to add some numbers to it, but `undefined + {anyNumber} = NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare variable

```
var sumUpArray;
```

is the same as

```
var sumUpArray = undefined;
```

So you try add integer to undefined results NaN

```
sumUpArray = sumUpArray + myArray[i];
sumUpArray = undefined + myArray[i]; // NaN
```

BTW: use `let` and `const` to declare variables.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use `var sumUpArray`, `sumUpArray` is `undefined`, not 0. `undefined` + any number will return `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

`var name;` is declared but not assigned or initialized or defined and hence is `undefined` however `var name=0;` is assigned a value '0'. typeof(name) will tell you that both are having different types.