# Why i get NaN instead of incrementing the value?

Tags: javascript

If i have an array like this:

```
const x = [{a: 1}];
```

and a function that should increment **a** property every time that function called:

```
function increment() {
  x[0] = {
    a: x.a + 1
  }

 return x;
}

console.log(increment()) // [{a: NaN}]
```

Shouldn't the function increment **a** instead of **NaN**??

Comment: because `x` is an arary, and arrays don't have the property `a`, `x` is not your object

Comment: oh yes, that is right

Comment: thank you, i can not believe that this took some time struggling!!!!

Comment: `x.a` will be `undefined`. When you try to add `1` to `undefined`, it returns `NaN`. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14977803/2924577

Comment: `x[0].a += 1` would be the better way to do it

Answer (score 1):

`x[0].a` instead of `x.a` since `x` is an array of objects.

```
function increment() {
    x[0] = {
        a: x[0].a + 1
    }
    return x;
}
```