# How OR logical assignment works in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
function maxChecker(str) {
  let final = {};
  for (let char of str) {
    final[char] = final[char] + 1 || 1;
  }

  return final;
}
```

If in this code I don't use the expression `|| 1` then my values in object is `NAN` kindly explain this

```
final[char]= final[char]+1 || 1;
```

Comment: What do you expect `final[char]` to be before you add the `+1`? Also what is the goal of this code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript OR (||) variable assignment explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation) and [what's the result of 1 + undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977569/whats-the-result-of-1-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get is [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), because of adding to [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) a value.

```js
console.log(undefined + 1);
```

But what is more a problem of this pattern, you move a error to a second step without using a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, like `undefined` of `final[char]`.

A better approach is to check if you get a falsy value and if so take zero as number, instead of `undefined` and add a value like `1` in the second step.

```
final[char] = (final[char] || 0) + 1;
```